# excel xlwings_udfs module is empty

Tags: udf, xlwings

Using xlwings 0.7.1 UDF on Windows in 64-bit virtual env python 2.7.6.
I see now that instead of requiring full path to module, it takes module names. However it fails silently to import any UDFs when the module name has package name prefixed. Eg:

```
PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & ";C:\pathTo\Pydev\myproj\src"
UDF_MODULES = "pkg.myudfs"
```

If I **move** the package name 'pkg' from UDF_MODULES to PYTHONPATH, then it fails at imports inside myudfs.py (like 'import pkg.module2').
After hit & trial, I fixed it by adding multiple source folders:

```
PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & ";C:\pathTo\Pydev\myproj\src\pkg;C:\pathTo\Pydev\myproj\src"
```

Am I expected to do this? Can't I just point UDF_MODULES to base src folder and provide qualified module name like 'pgk.myudfs'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually doing it right for right now (v0.7.1). I have, however, opened an [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/437) on GitHub so we might make this easier in a future release.

Comment: thanks. Btw, a comment regarding pip installation. When installing using **virtual env**, it seems the xlwings DLLs are not automatically copied to the Scripts directory. Other files like 'xlwings.exe' & 'xlwings-script.py' are properly copied to Scripts folder though. Is that by design? To make it work, I manually copied them from egg folder. Please let me know if it was not needed.

Comment: The design is that the dlls get copied next to the virtualenv python interpreter...Please open an issue on GitHub if you run into troubles with virtualenv.